# how to implement "blog" page in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, templates

Silly newbie question. I see a lot of HTML templates on Themeforest or other sites, and they usually include a blog page. Doesn't a blog require a CMS, such as Wordpress? If I want to create a blog in HTML/CSS for a single author website that does NOT contain comments, what are my best options? Do people commonly do this, or should I really be using a CMS even though it's such a simple thing?

I plan to use Bootstrap to build a website. The website also needs a blog, although it's not it's main focus. I prefer to avoid a CMS if at all possible (and don't want to build my own CMS). Are there any mainstream solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always be able use a text editor to modify files, regardless of their type.  That being said, if this template is built for a specific CMS (take Wordpress, for instance) you will need to have some sort of web server and database to develop against.

If this template is simply a bunch of HTML template/boilerplate files, you can develop all the pages you need by hand.  Just make copies and rename them according to your IA.

A blog *typically* implies you have some sort of database and CMS, but not always.  You could create static, hard-coded pages and call them your blog.

Comment: thanks @johnniebenson, so I'd have to manage all the tagging and linking for the blog pages manually. Are there no mainstream solutions for setting up a simple blog without requiring a CMS?

Comment: @user46688 You are correct...you would handle all of that manually if developing the pages by hand.  Most blogging platforms double as a CMS, but you can always have a hard-coded site and only use a CMS for your blog pages.  Wordpress is probably the most mainstream solution around.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a plain html template you can edit it by using various html/css/js editors such as brackets, atom, visual studio code or any other. On one hand, you can write your own CMS in e.g. php, ror, node. Or if you only want to have a blog site, you can buy a wordpress or joomla template and just install it into your CMS.

Answer (score 1):

In static pages , you can only update your blog page by your server's cpanel editor not by dynamically, so if you need this as dynamic then you have make a back end dashboard in any scripting language such as php, jsp, asp or any framework or cms. So, your template only can hold blogs statically, by writing before uploading the page on server, or edit the page from cpannel. Thanx.

Comment: Thanks @AnkitGupta, I'm not familiar with any HTML/CSS IDEs or advanced editors, but I assumed since blogs and HTML are so popular that something should be available for me to write the blog locally, allow me to enter tags, then generate the static pages accordingly for me to upload. Anything like that available?

Comment: yes , there are many IDEs and editors, You may use Notepad++, Adobe Dreamweaver and also there are more but for a beginner these are simple and most familiar for simple web design to complex designs including responsive. Also you can use the free web servers like Hostingner for your basic practice at server. else if you have more queries. So can message me anytime.